# Error in using Azure Storage JavaScript client library for browsers to create Shared Access Signature from

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-storage

I have a requirement to create blob section in a client application which will enable end users to upload images to Azure storage account.

I have create a container "test" with container level privilege following up from below link:

[New Azure Storage JavaScript client library for browsers - Preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/new-azure-storage-javascript-client-library-for-browsers-preview/)

I have created a simple HTML page and included Azure libraries in the specified order. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Media Upload</title>
<script src="azure-storage.common.js"></script/>
<script src="azure-storage.blob.js"></script/>

</head>
<body style="word-wrap: break-word;">

<input type="text" id="text" name="text" value="Hello World!" />
<button id="upload-button" onclick="uploadBlobFromText()">Upload</button>


<script>
function uploadBlobFromText() {
     // your account and SAS information
     var sasKey ="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
     var blobUri = "https://XXXXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net"; //tried with http as well.
     var blobService = AzureStorage.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, sasKey).withFilter(new AzureStorage.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter());
     alert("service ready");    
         var text = document.getElementById('text');
         var btn = document.getElementById("upload-button");
         blobService.createBlockBlobFromText('test', 'myblob', text.value,  function(error, result, response){
             if (error) {
                 alert('Upload failed, open browser console for more detailed info.');
                 console.log(error);
             } else {
                 alert('Upload successfully!');
             }
         });
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Status code: 404, description: 'The specified resource does not exist
```

Not sure why it is failing, can anyone help on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement **CORS** in your code.

> In the absence of CORS, websites that use Windows Azure Storage service would need to act as a proxy for storage calls.
>
> a typical usage for CORS for Blobs would be to allow direct Web Browser file upload against a Windows Azure Storage account. In this case, a user can use CORS along with SAS (Shared Access Signature) authentication mechanism in order to grant Web Browser write privilege to your storage account.

**Sample JavaScript Code for uploading a Blob to Windows Azure Storage**:

This below sample is a code snippet that would allow you to upload a file directly from the Web Browser into Windows Azure Storage using JavaScript. The full code is available in here. The code below is a snippet from the UploadImage.cshtml file.

```
// Method uploads a blob to Azure Storage by using a Blob SAS URL.
    // The Web Browser will add the necessary CORS headers and issue a preflight request if needed.
    // blobSasUrl: Blob SAS URL already obtained through an Ajax call to own service
    // fileDataAsArrayBuffer: an ArrayBuffer (Byte Array) containing the raw data of the file to be uploaded
    function uploadImage(blobSasUrl, fileDataAsArrayBuffer) {
        var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
        // Once the image is successfully upload, we will call render Image that would show the uploaded image
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {return renderImage(ajaxRequest, blobSasUrl)};
    
        try {
            // Performing a PutBlob (BlockBlob) against storage
            ajaxRequest.open('PUT', blobSasUrl, true);
            ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
            ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
            ajaxRequest.send(fileDataAsArrayBuffer);
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("can't upload the image to server.\n" + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

More info can be found [**here**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors/)